# Mod_rewrite question - what does this code for files do?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

I was researching .htaccess on here, and decided to try this code I'd found:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1 [T=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```

What does this do exactly? I know it's a rewrite rule, but what does the [T=] indicate?

I'm aware R is redirect, but this is a new one on me, so it'd be useful to know what this is.

Also, what do the regex symbols after RewriteRule indicate? I'm refreshing my knowledge on this, having realized I need good .htaccess skills for my project!

I understand some of mod_rewrite and .htaccess and have researched it myself, but this one is fairly new, so all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thanks for that, did look there. I knew the last bit, the MIME types. It was the part after RewriteRule with the dollar signs I'm not sure of...

Comment: That is a quite common regular-expression syntax.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk here, but if your question is "how do I learn regular-expression syntax?", that's a different question than what you're nominally asking. (And probably off-topic.)

Comment: OK, this can be locked then, since I made a small mistake. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T = set content-type (or MIME-type) header